# Matlab Loss of precision computing variance

Tags: matlab, statistics, variance

I have this vector [10000000000 10000000001 10000000002]

and i try to calculate its variance using this formula

[image: formula]

i calculate it but the answer that i get is  3.33333333466667e+19
which is wrong, because the correct answer is 1.

What i am doing wrong?

the MATLAB code is

```
    total=0;
    m1=data(1);
    m2=(data(2)-m1)/2;
    q1=0;
    q2=q1+(((2-1)/2)*((data(2)-m1)^2));
    q3=q2+(((3-1)/3)*((data(3)-m2)^2));
    variance=q3/(3-1)
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you forget the `m3 = (datos(3)-m2)/3` step? (Not that I have a clue why you _do_ that, I just noticed a missing step from your image...)

Comment: i dont need m3 because the q3 formula only requires to have the value of q2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

M is a mean calculation, it is supposed to be

```
Mk = ((k-1) M(k-1) + xk)/k
```

thus

```
m1=data(1);
m2=(data(2)+m1)/2;
q1=0;
q2=q1+(((2-1)/2)*((data(2)-m1)^2));
q3=q2+(((3-1)/3)*((data(3)-m2)^2));
variance=q3/(3-1)
variance =
     1
```

what the heck, I'm feeling generous, the complete code for a generic size data:

```
sizle = size(data,2);
M = zeros(1, sizle);
Q = M;
Variance = Q;
M(1)=data(1);
for i = 2:sizle
    M(i)=((i-1)*M(i-1) + data(i))/i;
    Q(i)=Q(i-1)+(i-1)*((data(i)-M(i-1))^2)/i;
    Variance(i) = Q(i)/(i-1);
end

Variance(end)
var(data)
```